# Mysql Comparison in where clauses between two subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, comparison, subquery

Is there any way, using Mysql, to compare the result of two subqueries in where clause in an insert statement ?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
insert into table1 (field1, field2) values (....) where (select sum(x) from table2 where ..) <= (select sum(y) from table3 where ..)
```

In this example, we assume that x and y are numeric values.

Thanks you for your help

Comment: MySql has [`INSERT`-`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) construct. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: +1 to @PM77-1, because INSERT does not allow a WHERE clause. Can't guess what you intend this statement to do. Can you describe?

Comment: What are the values you are intending to insert in the event that the condition is met?  Are they literal values supplied that you supply in your SQL, or are they taken from `table2` and `table3`?

Comment: @Bill Karwin : You're right. I didn't use sql for a long time so I didn't remember that insert doesn't allow where clause...
What I want to do is to insert a row only if a condition is met.
In my case, i would like to add a reservation if a location isn't fully booked.

Comment: @eggyal : Values come from an user so they are literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2) SELECT ?, ?
WHERE (SELECT SUM(x) FROM table2 WHERE ..) <= (SELECT SUM(y) FROM table3 WHERE ..)
```

But this logic seems very strange indeed and is probably indicative of a poor design.

Comment: I think this is the solution but perhaps it's poor design..
Here my two reduced tables only with interesting fields. Location (id, name, maxNumberOfPeople), Reservation (id, name, locationId, numberOfPeople)
Before accepting a reservation, I want to check that the chosen location as enough space to accomodate the bookers. What would you do in this case ?

Comment: @Keen: One would normally use a database *transaction* in which one reads from the tables, verifies that the current state of the database supports the desired change, then commits that change to the database; if done correctly, such an operation will be performed "atomically" from the perspective of any other database connections thus avoiding inconsistent data.

Comment: That's it. I would like to avoid inconsistent data but I have to use only sql query to perform the action. The case is in the context of a school exercise so I can't use database transaction. But I'll remember it for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

I think about:

```
SELECT @sum_x:=sum(x)FROM table2 WHERE ..
SELECT @sum_y:=sum(x)FROM table3 WHERE ..
INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2) SELECT *(what do you want) FROM ???? WHERE  @sum_x ??? @sum_y 
// Do not know what are you trying to insert actually and on what condition
```

Look at join operation. [Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)
I think that you need to join table2 and table3 and after it, make comparation and selection. May be it will help with your design.

Comment: The problem is that your condition is useless. I suppose that you plan to join tables, otherwise your condition can be true/false and it will not depent on first table. What you actually get is:
1) Copy everything from (I do not now from what)
2) Copy nothing.